# SharePoint 2010 - prevent My Site access for some users

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, access-denied

I have the situation that we have two SP2010 farms, one for internal and one for internal and external users (different AD's, with trust relationship).

Goal:
I want to have only MySites for internal users. External users have no access to the internal server and should only see the "simple profile page" for all users. While internal users should always have access to the MySite (from internal or external farm).

What I did so far:
I have set-up the MySite Application in the internal farm. I have added a trusted host location on the external farm and also set the user permissions, so that external users cannot create MySites.

What works:
External users can only select "My Settings" (simple profile) from the Welcome menu and Internal Users can select "About me" (My Site).

What doesn't work:
When an external user clicks on a Username of an internal user, he is redirected to the MySite of that user --> access denied. I want him to just see the "simple profile page".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run fiddler to make sure your setup works the same as mine, but the way mine works is it takes me down the following URL path (some extra querystring parameters changed/removed for a cleaner view below):

```
https://external.company.com/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=guid&ID=1
https://external.company.com/my/Person.aspx?accountname=userid&Source=sourceurl&Title=sourcetitle
https://mysite.company.com/my/Person.aspx?accountname=userid
```

This means I can put maybe a webpart or some type of code on the `https://external.company.com/my/Person.aspx` page to do the following:

1. Check to see if the user if in the external domain.
2. Use the source querystring parameter to redirect the user back to the "simple profile page".  In my instance it even included the needed force=1 querystring value which will force not to redirect to the mysite page.

You will also need to edit the person.aspx in SP Designer and move the `SPSWC:PersonalSpacePublicRedirect` control futher down the page so it happens AFTER your custom webpart.  Or add your custom webpart before it on the page.  Either way, SP Designer would be required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however in my case the internal site is not even accessible (firewall) for external users, so they actually get 404 error.

Comment: If you look at the url I was referring to, it is the mysite host that is located on your EXTERNAL environment.

Comment: I'll check with my client if it's ok to have the MySites on the external server, it might not. I wonder if I can remove the redirect from the userdisp.aspx on the external farm (I'm aware of the upgrade-ability problem).

Comment: Well, on my external farm I have a user profile service application created and a mysite host.  But in the user profile service application permissions, i didn't allow external users the ability to create a personal site, use social features, etc.  From my experience, this was required in order to get the separation I needed while also allowing internal users the ability to follow content.